# SQLite update function

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I have a database that holds only one value. It has two columns which are "id" and "status". id = 1 and status = FALSE. I want to update my table to TRUE when a condition that I wrote satisfied.

```
    System.out.println("!!!!!entered here!!!!!!!!!");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("1", "TRUE");
    System.out.println("!!!!!entered here!!!!!!!!!");       

    db.update("main", cv, "id = 1", null);
    System.out.println("??????not entered here??????");
```

It forces me to quit and ofcourse not updated my table.

I'm trying this for checking a condition and if it is satisfied it makes status TRUE. If status is FALSE, my app enters CheckScreen and if it is TRUE my app won't enter in that screen.

I'm also listening your solutions to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your content values :

```
 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
 cv.put("1", "TRUE");
```

Should be

```
   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
   cv.put("status", "TRUE");
```

status is the column name you are updating.

For e.g:

```
 DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
 SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
 updateValues.put("status", "TRUE");
 int updated = db.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, updateValues, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
```

Comment: firstly, it was "status" but I had same error. --> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: post your log cat error, Ill edit my post based on the error log

Comment: do you have another solution to offer? how can I make user enter to the CheckScreen only for the first time?

Comment: What is checkscreen? your question is about updating a row data in sqllite inst it?

Comment: A screen of my app. User enters a code with 16 characters in that screen for only once. phone updates the database as status = true and if status = true, user won't see the checkscreen again in whole life.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, I used Shared Preferences. My purpose is holding a status on the device which is initially "false" and when user downloads the app, enters the password, make that status "true".

My Intro.class

```
    SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("xmlFile", MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean checkValue = mSharedPrefs.getBoolean("bool", false);
    if (checkValue) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intro.this, MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intro.this, KeyCheckClass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My KeyCheckClass.class

```
...
private boolean check(String str) {
        // my validation algorithm
    }

    SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("xmlFile",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();

    mPrefsEditor.putBoolean("bool", true);
    mPrefsEditor.commit();

    return true;
}
```

On my MainScreen.class my app makes a real start. Now, after entering a valid password, phone doesn't get into the KeyCheckClass.class again, passes it through MainScreen.class